# question regarding the existence of measurable subset with positive measure

Tags: measure-theory

It is well-known that any measurable set with a positive measure has a non-measurable subset. But how about the related question: whether there always exists a measurable subset with positive measure in a non-measurable set.

Intuitively I would say yes. But not sure how to provide a proof. Please help prove or refute it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure)?

Comment: @cardinal: right, I know the concept. so...?

Comment: I think what cardinal's getting at is that a generalized version of this question would have the answer no for any incomplete measure, as seen by taking any nonmeasurable subset of a set of measure $0$.

Comment: I'm probably too tired to be thinking or reading straight. However, let $B \subset A$ such that $\mu(A) = 0$ and $B$ is non measurable. Then any subset $C \subset B$ that is measurable must have measure zero by monotonicity. You seem to be asking something quite strong, i.e., that for every non measurable set, there exists *some* measurable subset *and* furthermore that it have positive measure.

Comment: @cardinal: Lebesgue measure is complete. All subsets of a set of measure 0 are measurable with measure 0. By the way, this shows there are measurable sets that are non-Borel, by a cardinality argument.

Comment: That's true for Lebesgue measure on the real line. But that's not stated in the OP's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vitali's non-measurable subset $V\subset S^1=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (obtained by choosing one representative from each class modulo $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$) doesn't have such a subset. If $A\subset V$ is measurable then $A+q\,$'s are measurable and disjoint for different $q\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, hence $\sum_q\mu(A+q)\leq \mu(S^1)=1$, and $\mu(A+q)=\mu(A)$ for every $q$, hence $\mu(A)=0$.

Answer (score 5):

A key definition here is "inner measure".  The Lebesgue inner measure of a set $A$ is the supremum of the measures of the Lebesgue measurable subsets of $A$ (equivalently, of the closed subsets of $A$).  You are asking whether every nonmeasurable set has positive inner measure, and as user8268 has shown, the answer is no.

A set of real numbers $A$ of finite outer measure is measurable if and only if its Lebesgue inner measure $m_*(A)$ is equal to its Lebesgue outer measure $m^*(A)$.  If $m^*(A)=m_*(A)$, then there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ and an $F_\sigma$ set $F$ such that $F\subseteq A\subseteq G$ and $m(F)=m_*(A)=m^*(A)=m(G)$.  Then $A\setminus F\subseteq G\setminus F$ is a null set, and therefore $A=F\cup(A\setminus F)$ is measurable.

Let $A$ be a nonmeasurable set with finite inner measure.  Let $F\subset A$ be an $F_\sigma$ such that $m(F)=m_*(A)$.  Then $A\setminus F$ is a nonmeasurable set with inner measure $0$.  Thus, every nonmeasurable set contains nonmeasurable subsets with no measurable subsets of positive measure.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Originally answered this as yes, but obviously the answer is no (poor proofreading skills, sorry).

The key here is that Lebesgue measure is *[regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure)*. Any of the equivalent formulations of regularity gives you that any set contains a measurable subset with the same *inner* measure. Of course, if the outer and inner measures of a set coincide, then the set is measurable. So any non-measurable set $A$ must have positive outer measure. Its inner measure is the sup of the measures of its compact subsets, so $A$ contains an $F_\sigma$ set with the same inner measure, so their difference has inner measure zero and is non-measurable. This gives the result.

Comment: yes, I know the non-measurable set has positive outer measure. But how to show it has a subset which is measurable and has positive measure?

Comment: The inner measure is the sup of the measures of compact subsets, right? So there is an $F_\sigma$ subset whose measure is the outer measure of your set.

Comment: There is an $F_\sigma$ in the set whose measure is the inner measure of the set, but if the outer measure is finite this will be less than the outer measure for a nonmeasurable set.

Comment: (Right, that's what I get for not proofreading what I write.)

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks for spotting the non-sense.