# Does infinite outer measure implies infinite inner measure?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Just came over this question in my mind: if I know a set has an infinite outer measure, does it mean it also has to have an infinite inner measure.

Comment: [This is related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/question-regarding-the-existence-of-measurable-subset-with-positive-measure)  The question isn't quite the same, but the answers provide the essential arguments.

Comment: A subset of the reals can have zero inner measure and infinite outer measure. In fact, a set with zero inner measure can be such that for each interval $I,$ the outer measure of its intersection with $I$ has outer measure equal to the length of $I.$ Seemingly even stronger (but I believe this will follow automatically from the interval property), a set with zero inner measure can "fill up the real line" so much that, for each set $E$ of positive (including infinite) measure, its intersection with $E$ will have outer measure equal to the measure of $E.$

Comment: Regarding the claims I just made, see [Is there a maximum to the amount of disjoint non-measurable subsets of the unit interval with full outer measure?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit). See also this [5 February 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4273307).

Answer (score 1):

There exists $A\subset \Bbb R$ such that for any uncountable closed $C\subset \Bbb R$ we have $C\cap A\ne \emptyset \ne C \cap (\Bbb R\setminus A)$.

Any closed subset of $A$ is countable so $A$ has inner measure $0.$

Any closed subset of $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is also countable. So if $U$ is open and $U\supset A$ then $\Bbb R\setminus U$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R\setminus A,$ so $\Bbb R\setminus U$ is countable, so $U$ has infinite measure.

Comment: could you please explain why such a A exists?

Comment: @Risto . Look up Bernstein Set on this site or on wikipedia.

Comment: got it. thanks a lot! in fact i asked a duplicated question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4225931